# Can't see php-content from custom template in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm trying to create a custom template for a small wordpress site, the template should display some data from the database.

But I can't get PHP to output anything on the pages, I've written a few echo's just to get something but can't see anything.

I can, however, add the page through "Pages" in WordPress, that works just fine and displays an empty page (or with text if I write something in the text box)

To set up the template I created a child template of my original template, the CSS file in the child template works just fine.

I added the custom page called "petitionlist.php" in the root of my child-theme, the code I added for testing is as following

```
<?php 
/* 
Template Name: petitionlist
*/ 
get_header(); 

    echo "test test test"; 
    $test = "testtetsttest"; 
    echo "<h1> this is a test</h1>".$test; ?> 
    <h1>Hello wordl!</h1> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Attached is a screenshot of my folder-structure, the petitionlist.php file in wechange-child is the file I'm working on.

[image: Screenshot of my folder structure]

Comment: Try "View source" to see if something is outputted (eliminating that this is just a CSS issue)

Comment: did you assign this template to the page?

Comment: The text is not displayed in view source, just double checked.

Comment: Akshay yes I assigned it via "Pages", it's just empty. I can write text into it though.

Comment: Do the header and footer come out fine?

Comment: ... and do you see the <h1>Hello wordl!</h1> that is not part of the php code?

Comment: It is a single page site, i just saw that if I open the page as it's own page instead of viewing it on the single page the output from the PHP actually displays

Comment: So you mean to say on the page link it is showing your string but on home page it is not showing? Am i getting you correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct